# Laravel 8: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm making a forum with Laravel 8. And I want to return a question and show the name of the user who has asked this question.

At the Model `User.php` I coded this:

```
public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
```

And also I put this at `Question.php` Model:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

So in order to get the name of a user who has asked the question, I put this:

```
{{ $show->users->name }}
```

But now I get this error message:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**

So what's going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

Note that this `$show` variable comes from this Controller Method and gets the question information:

```
public function showQuestion($slug)
    {
        $show = Question::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        if(is_null($show)){
            abort(404);
        }

        return view('questions.question',[
            'show' => $show
        ]);
    }
```

And also each question has stored the `user_id` of the user who has asked this question:

[image: capture]

So if you have any idea or suggestion on this, please let me know, I would really appreciate that!

> **Update #1:**

Here is the table `users`:

[image]

> **Update #2:**

`questions` table migration:

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->string('private')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

`users` table migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('phone')->unique();
            $table->binary('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('job')->nullable();
            $table->string('location')->nullable();
            $table->string('bio')->nullable();
            $table->string('skills')->nullable();
            $table->string('stackoverflow')->nullable();
            $table->string('github')->nullable();
            $table->string('instagram')->nullable();
            $table->string('linkedin')->nullable();
            $table->string('website')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you put your `queations` migration file?

Comment: @Droid Yes, I do have

Comment: @Droid I just added a capture of my `users` table.

Comment: try {{  $show->users}} , share the result

Comment: @OMR Nothing appears! *Null*

Comment: @Droid I just added migration of `users` and `questions` tables. See #update2, and thank u

Comment: the relationship method should be named `user` not `users`

Comment: @lagbox You have saved my life, thank u so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship on Question to User should be named `user` instead of `users`. When you are letting Eloquent automatically figure out the fields for the `belongsTo` relationship it actually uses the name of the relationship method to help determine what the foreign key is.

If you don't want to follow that type of convention with naming the method like that you can explicitly set the foreign key used by the `belongsTo` method:

```
public function belongsTo($related, $foreignKey = null, $ownerKey = null, $relation = null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the function name users to user in Question model.  when you are letting Eloquent automatically figure out the relationship you have to name the function regarding to their relationships like one to one or one to many or many to many.

Try this

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }


{{ $show->user->name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for show function in controller
`$student= Student::all();`
`return view('showData',['data' => $student]);`

and for view to show data
`@foreach($data as $stud)`
   `<tr>`
       `<td>{{$stud)->id}}</td>`
       `<td>{{$stud)->name}}</td>`
   `</tr>`
`@endforeach`

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
```

*switch to like this, I switched to hasOne and it worked well*

```
return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id')
  ->withDefault(['name' => '']);
```